Unable to change App Configuration of published Workspace Marketplace app
I have a publicly published Workspace Marketplace app, i.e. it has gone through review with approval.
The app has been published and working nicely for 5 months, but I wanted to make a small change to the app configuration, specifically updating the developer email. However when I try to make any change to the app configuration or even no change at all, clicking the "save draft" button always results in OAuth scope errors that prevent the configuration from being saved.

OAuth scopes have not been modified in any way, but I assume saving the configuration runs a full validation which prompts the scope issues. The app was approved with these exact scopes, but now any attempt at saving the configuration results in the OAuth scopes being highlighted as issues and the new configuration cannot be saved.
"Users may see the unverified app screen" sounds to me like users will see the app as unverified when prompted for scopes, until the app has been re-reviewed and approved, which I am fine with if that is required. However I cannot even get to that point as it stands due to draft saving being blocked, so I am unsure of my next steps.

I'll check and keep an eye on the issue tracker, thanks.

There are actually multiple posts that have the same issue over the past hour. Though the next action should be with a Google Cloud Console Support to confirm how to navigate the system I would also suggest posting what is happening with your project here. Issuetracker.google.com
Updating this comment for future readers in case it happens again: Updated link on the issue tracker for better referencing.

Resolved
To conclude this issue.
The issue has now been fixed with a presumed patch to the Workspace Marketplace SDK on Googles side. App configuration changes can once again be saved.
